# Admob crashes in ios13 but works on ios14

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, admob

So I have a number of apps that were working fine. Just recently I tried some of them out on an earlier iOS (13.5) in the simulator and they ALL crash when I load the advert (interstitial.load or banner.load). They were ALL working on earlier simulators previously (some of them are a few years old so iOS 14 didn't even exist).
The error is:
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

I don't understand what this means but there is no other context so Ive been struggling to understand what the issue is. It always stops at the .load line.

I am using app tracking transparency but have tried removing it and still get the same behaviour.

Has anyone else experienced this??

I don't know if its on real devices or just the simulators...(I don't have a real device with an old iOS to test it on).
Ive a feeling it might be to do with all the new privacy stuff that's flying around.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. Any news?

Comment: nope. nobody has got back to me. I think its just the simulator as my apps aren't showing any crashes on the App Store but not sure....

Comment: Encountering the same issue